# How to get the first element in ResultSet

Tags: java, resultset

How to get the first element in ResultSet in the following code:

```
    public List getUserTest(String username, String password) {

    List userList = new ArrayList();


    Connection connection = null;
    String rstring = null;
    Statement stmt = null;///*******
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {

        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();///*******
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username)='" + username + "'"
                + "AND (password)='" + password + "'");///*******

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            UsersTest user = new UsersTest();
            user.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
            user.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
            user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
            userList.add(user);
        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {

            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }

            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
    return  userList;
}
```

Comment: Since you got good answers to your question, you should make the effort to show your appreciation by selecting one of them as the accepted answer.  It's proper SO etiquette.

Answer (score 5):

The first element of the ResultSet is the one that you're working with the first time you execute the `while (resultSet.next())` loop, and therefore its contents are used to build the first element of `userList`.

Comment: But if you focus on while (resultSet.next()), you will find I used list to add all records. So, what about If I want just to get the first records and no need to add the rest records in query. I other word, I need just the first element in the list as in the code above.

Comment: Right, what about If I want just to get the first element in the List although its contents has more on record. (Only the first record and ignore the rest)

Comment: If you want just the first row from the RestultSet, then instead of `while(resultSet.next())`, just do `if(resultSet.next())`.

Answer (score 5):

Do:

```
resultSet.first()
```

Check the API here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

PS:

In my opinion is better to replace:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
        UsersTest user = new UsersTest();
        user.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
        user.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
        user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
        userList.add(user);
    }
```

With: **(RETURNS OBJECT)**

```
if (!rs.next())
  //No user found.
else {
  UsersTest user = new UsersTest();
  resultSet.first();
  user.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
  user.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
  user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
}

return user;
```

Return list: **(RETURNS LIST)**

```
List userList = new ArrayList();

if (!rs.next())
  //No user found.     
else {
  UsersTest user = new UsersTest();
  resultSet.first();
  user.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
  user.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
  user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
  userList.add(user) //it will only add one element
}

return userList;
```

To call your method do:

```
UsersTest u = new UserTest();
List l = getUserTest(username, password)

if(l.size > 0)
  u = l.get(0);
else
  System.out.println("Cannot find user");
```

I suggest that because I do not think that you will have 2 results(List is unnecessary). You expect to have 0 or 1 result!

Comment: What do you mean  User u = resultSet.first();  (( User  ))

Comment: If I copy your code and replace it to my code, It shows error (boolean caanot ve dereferenced)

Comment: Thanks and please what about If I want to convert it to list?

Comment: Return a list with this method instead of a user?

Comment: I want to still use List, that means I want to get the first element of ResultSet and convert it to List which has only the one record

Comment: Yes that right but the problem is that returns Object Of UserTest but I want return List of oe element?

Comment: It returns `return userList;` your userlist mate. Check the code again. I didn't delete the part for returning an object. but I added another part for returning a list.

Comment: Sorry If I bother you, but really I need your help. There is problem in the condtion: if (resultSet.getFetchSize() > 0) When I try to get some result drom database it gives me null although i put the username & password correct?

Comment: No prob mate. Try it now! I think it should be ok.

Comment: Mate , I made debug and I found the problem in this line resultSet.first(); but I dont know why

Comment: The exception is :Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY.

Comment: Many thanks Mate I appreciate that. You really help me and the last problem which is ((Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY. )) I solved through adding {{{{ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE}}}} to connection to be as the following: stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); ) Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A ResultSet is not a Java collection so there is no real first element. You have access to the columns of the first returned row in the first iteration of the

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
while(resultSet.next())
{
 ...
}
```

loop.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
List users = List getUserTest(username, password);
User user = ((users.size() > 0 ? users.get(0) : null);
```

The truth is that your database ought to enforce the idea that a username/password combination ought to be enough to identify a unique individual.  A query should either return a unique individual or null.  Your code as written will behave this way if your database has this constraint.

If it doesn't, you need to think about your schema design.

Comment: @duffmo actually the username alone should be enuf to uniquely identify an individual.  The password should never be stored in the database.  So there is already reason to doubt the schema design.

Comment: Please can you edit your code depending on my code to make it very clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `if(resultSet.first)...` instead of `while(resultSet.next)...`
but if you want to get all results and then choose the first from all this is a way to do so :

```
List<UsersTest> users = new ArrayList<UsersTest>();
while(resultSet.next){
   UsersTest user = new UsersTest();
   /*
      * All your Setters but you should create a constructor with fields
   */
   users.add(user);
}
```

and to get the first result `UsersTest firstUser = users.get(0);`